# Starting threads from within a function

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I am very new to posix threads, and I need help starting and managing threads from within a function, is this possible?

I have read through the examples on github, they are very helpful but I have still not been able to implement a solution.

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/tree/master/examples

I have logic that continually adds tasks to RabbitMQ. I then have logic that consumes these tasks and runs them. I want to use pthreads to run them in parallel - so each time a task is added to rabbitmq a thread is immediately started to handle it.

RabbitMQ calls a function or a class method ( that I specify ) whenever there is a task to be consumed.

*This code has been simplified so its easier to read*

To prove I have pthreads installed and working, this works:

```
<?php
$workers = [];
foreach (range(0, 5) as $i) {
    $workers[$i] = new WorkerThread($i);
    $workers[$i]->start();
}
```

This does not work:

```
<?php
$workers = [];
$callback = function($msg)
{
    $i = $msg->uniqueKey;
    $workers[$i] = new WorkerThread($i, $msg);
    $workers[$i]->start();
};
$channel->basic_consume('queue', '', false, true, false, false, $callback );
```

My problem is that I cannot initialize and start a thread from within the function and have them run in parallel.

I have also tried starting the thread directly instead of having to call the function. But that doesn't work because I have to call the start method and cannot do that and send additional arguments, even if I could by overwriting that method and calling the parent that would be a huge hack:

```
$channel->basic_consume('queue', '', false, true, false, false, [ new WorkerThread(), 'start' ] );
```

How is it best to start pthreads from with a function or method?

I realize this may be a very beginner question, perhaps a bad question, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, else there would be no execution for any process!

Comment: ```use ($workers)``` appears to be missing ... at the moment, ```$workers``` is destroyed when control leaves the Closure, this destroys the ```WorkerThread``` it contains ...

Comment: I have implemented `$callback = function($msg) use ($workers)` but I get the same result- all the logic runs, but still not in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Use globals. The changes from inside the function will become garbage after the function ends, unless it is a global variable.

Comment: No? Can you elaborate?